# Need help regarding the implementation of logic for multiple conditions

Tags: java, json, validation, if-statement

I need some help in identifying the logic to implement the following conditions below:

I have a search criteria request which can can have around 10 possible combinations. Im writing the request validation for it with proper error messages.

These are my conditions :

```
         if (request.getFullName() == null && request.getFullNameEs() == null && request.getBirthDate() == null && request.getNat() == null &&
                request.getGender() == null) {
            validationErrors.add("Name criteria search is not proper");
        }
        if (request.getPassportNo() != null) {
            if (request.getPassportNationality() == null && request.getBirthYear() == null) {
                errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, "Please pass passportNationality or birthYear ");
            }
            if (request.getPassportTypeId() == null || request.getPassportNationality() == null) {
                errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, "Please pass passportTypeId and/or passportNationality");
            }
        } else {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, "Please pass passportNo");
        }
        if (request.getIdNo() == null) {
            if (request.getIdType() == null || request.getIdNationalityId() == null) {
                errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, "Please pass IdType and/or IdNationalityId");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, "Please pass idNo");
        }
        if (request.getPersonNo() == null && request.getPersonTypeId() == null) {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (request.getSponsorNo() == null && request.getSponsorTypeId() == null && request.getPpsId() == null) {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (request.getSponsorNo() == null && request.getSponsorTypeId() == null && request.getPpsId() == null) {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (request.getSponsorNo() == null) {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        if (request.getPersonNo() == null && request.getPersonTypeId() == null) {
            errors.reject(NULL_OR_EMPTY_FIELD_ERROR, ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
```

in one request, only of the criteria should be passed and it that particular criteria failed then I want the validation to break and display only that particular error message and not the list of messages.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly you can simply implement this as a function and return when a condition is true.

Comment: The issue is multiple conditions will fail and only one would pass but the error message contains all the failed msgs which are not for this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.  Use a block to contain the conditional tests and then selectively break out of the block.

```
        int a = 10;
        next:
        {
            if (a % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println("a is even");
                break next;
            }
            if (a > 6) {
                System.out.println("a > 6");
            }
            if (a > 7) {
                System.out.println("a > 7");
            }
        }
```

- If a is even it prints it and breaks out of the block.
- if a is odd it continues processing all the remaining conditionals

Note that you can have nested blocks and break statements.  Combined with the proper use of `else` this should help solve your issue.

Comment: Can you explain with my example?

Comment: Your example is extremely complicated.  Nor can I compile it to check on results since I don't have  your data structures.  If you could provide a simpler example (e.g. [mre]) of what you are looking for I could help.